# Spring-Boot & Spring-Security Configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to use Spring Security in my Spring-Boot project.

My project structure is:

```
/project
 -/src/main
 -- /java
 -- / resources
 --- /static
  ---- /css
  ---- /fonts
  ---- /libs
 --- /templates
  ---- /all html files
```

Here is my gradle settings:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'

project.ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.0.2.RELEASE'
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.0.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.0.M1")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.0.M1")
...
}
```

Each of my html files has this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>

    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/ofac.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Here is my MVC Config:
    @Configuration
    public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

```
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController( "/home" ).setViewName( "index" );
        registry.addViewController( "/" ).setViewName( "index" );
        registry.addViewController( "/about" ).setViewName( "about" );
        registry.addViewController( "/login" ).setViewName( "login" );
        registry.addViewController( "/upload" ).setViewName( "upload" );
        registry.addViewController( "/status" ).setViewName( "status" );
        registry.addViewController( "/search" ).setViewName( "search" );
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName( "lang" );
        registry.addInterceptor( localeChangeInterceptor );
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale( StringUtils.parseLocaleString( "en" ) );
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames( "classpath:messages/messages", "classpath:messages/validation" );
        // if true, the key of the message will be displayed if the key is not
        // found, instead of throwing a NoSuchMessageException
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage( true );
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding( "UTF-8" );
        // # -1 : never reload, 0 always reload
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds( 0 );
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Based on various examples I found online, I have the following security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/resources/**" ).permitAll();

        http
                .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll();

        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        userDetailsService.setDataSource( datasource );
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        auth.userDetailsService( userDetailsService ).passwordEncoder( encoder );
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource( datasource );

        if ( !userDetailsService.userExists( "user" ) ) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add( new SimpleGrantedAuthority( "USER" ) );
            User userDetails = new User( "user", encoder.encode( "password" ), authorities );

            userDetailsService.createUser( userDetails );
        }
    }
}
```

When I navigate to `localhost:9001`  I am prompted with my login page.  I provide the correct credentials and am redirected to the url: `http://localhost:9001/css/ofac.css`  the contents of my css file are shown.   Before I added the security, the pages would render correctly.  Once the login is successful, the css is shown, but if I navigate the root back to "/" then everything behaves as it should.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

**Update**:
I removed the following because Spring-boot will handle the /resources/**

```
http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers( "/resources/**" ).permitAll();
```

I also changed the redirect for successful login to:

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
```

because that is also mapped to "/"

However, the behavior is the same.  One interesting behavior is that when I use Safari, the login will give me "`http://localhost:9001/css/bootstrap.css`"  but Firefox will give me "`http://localhost:9001/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css`"

When I inspect the `POST http://localhost:9001/login` with Firebug I get a "302 Found" followed by a `GET http://localhost:9001/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css` that returns a 200.

Comment: `/css` is protected so as soon as it is request for that URL a login is shown after login you will be redirected to the url that triggered the login. I would expect that your css was available under `/resources/**` else include `/css/**` with a `permitAll()`.

Comment: My /css files are under /resources (updated original posting to show this) so I believe it would be exposed with my ".authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/resources/**" ).permitAll();"

Comment: Apparently something is requesting a css not from that directory check your templates.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Spring Boot automatically exposes everything under `/static`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: I made edits to my original post to show that this is still failing.  M.Deinum, I also updated to show how i am pulling in the css from my html pages - is that the correct way?

Comment: No it isn't… As I mentioned earlier `/css/` is protected. You will need to add that to your permit all. The fact that they are under resources is only true in maven `src/main/resources` is a default maven folder which will be added to your class path. What you have to do is make `/css` etc. all configured with `permitAll`.

Comment: Thank you M.Deinum - I thought that because /css/ was under /resources/ it would be covered by the ".antMatchers( "/resources/**" ).permitAll();"  but thanks to your comment, I added ".antMatchers( "/css/**" ).permitAll();" and now its working perfectly.

Comment: It is about securing URLs not about how things look internally to your app. The url starts with /css so have have to secure (or not) that.

Answer (score 6):

add this method to SecurityConfig

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity security){
    security.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**","/fonts/**","/libs/**"");
}
```

Comment: Seems like Spring Boot Security will only ignore auth for `/css/**`, `/images/**` and `/js/**`. I had to manually add the `/fonts/**` entry.

Comment: Yep, I had to do the similar (css, js were fine, but not fonts)... .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/fonts/**").permitAll()

Comment: how can we ignore these paths in Interceptor ?  though I am using excludePathpattern("/css") to ignore static content paths

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced Spring security blocking resources from the /static/fonts/ path. However, "/static/css", "/static/js", "/static/images" were permitted by default , but /static/fonts/** was blocked.

Below is an example of how I fixed this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
.....
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll().
        //other security configuration rules
    }
.....
}
```